# How can I convert an if..else if..else statement to a single formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

I have this program where I made a variable x, and I want to assign it a value based on this formula (where c is a positive integer):
$$
x = f(c) = 
\begin{cases}
c & c<100\\100 & 100<=c<200\\c-100 & c>=200
\end{cases}
$$
At the moment I have this in some code using an if statement, but I'd like to have this using a single assignment with just a formula and no if statements.

```
  int x;
  if (c < 100) 
    x = c;
  else if (c < 200)
    x = 100;
  else
    x = c-100;
```

I've heard that if statements like this can be converted into some formula, but I'm not sure where to start, any help would be appreciated!
In the end, I'll hopefully have just one statement:

```
int x = f(c);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:
$$f(c) = c-50+\frac{|c-200|-|c-100|}{2}$$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=c-50%2B%28%7Cc-200%7C-%7Cc-100%7C%29%2F2)

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you! How did you approach it to come up with this solution?

Comment: You are looking for a piecewise linear, continuous function, and the absolute value function is the simplest one of that kind. You have kinks at $c=100$ and $c=200$ so it stands to reason that the function you are looking for is some linear combination of $c$, $|c-100|$, and $|c-200|$. Then it is just a matter of figuring out the right coefficients to get the three slopes correct and the constant term to get the right value for $f(0)$.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very detailed and you responded so quickly! Hopefully I'll be able to come up with something like this next time I have a similar problem.

Comment: (-1) This works and from a mathematical perspective may be nice, but from a programming perspective this is not a good way of expressing this assignment. The problem is that it does not express the intention of the assignment, but instead uses a trick to get the correct value.

Comment: @Magdiragdag But we stand in a mathematics forum... so (+1).

Comment: In a mathematical context, the understandable way to express this function is exactly how the OP has done it. Also there, there is no reason to obfuscate the function.

Answer (score 2):

Most programming languages have some ternary-if function. In can look like
(c, c++, java)

```
int x = c < 100 ? c : c < 200 ? 100 : c - 100;
```

or (python)

```
x = c if c < 100 else 100 if c < 200 else c - 100
```

This cleanly expresses the intent of your assignment. Parenthesis are not needed in this case, but you may want to add them to make it even clearer, e.g.,

```
int x = c < 100 ? c : (c < 200 ? 100 : c - 100);
```

Now, these don't contain *if statements*, but they do contain *if expressions*. If you're not happy with that, you need to resort to trickery as in Jaap Scherphuis' answer.

Comment: On a minor tangent, you *do* need the parentheses if you're programming in PHP, since for some weird reason (probably just lack of proper design and planning) they [made the ternary conditional operator left-associative](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ternary_associativity). But in that case the *real* problem isn't the lack of parentheses, but the fact that you're using PHP. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In computability theory I've found the following notation

$f(x) = x\cdot \chi_{x<100} + 100 \cdot \chi_{100\leq x<200} + (x-100)\cdot \chi_{x\geq 200}$

where $\chi_A$ ($A$ is a set) is a 0-1 function such that $\chi_A (x) = 1$ if $x\in A$ and $0$ otherise.

Comment: I think this does not really address the OP's question, this just encodes if statements using the characteristic function.

Comment: But this expression can be implemented by procedure calls.

Comment: @Westenfux sure, but there are still "if" structures, even if they are encapsulated in the definition of the characteristic function. The answer by Jaap does not suffer from this handicap.

Comment: The absolute value function in Jaap's answer could be using if behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function like this

```
int f(int c){
  if (c < 100) 
    return c;
  else if (c < 200)
    return 100;
  else
    return c-100
}
```

Now you can call it in one statement like this, as required.

```
int x = f(c);
```